# having a problem with Property 'octomber' is used before its initialization

Tags: angular, chart.js

```
  @Component({
      selector: 'app-adminpanel',
      templateUrl: './adminpanel.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./adminpanel.component.scss']
    })
    export class AdminpanelComponent implements OnInit {
      msg='';
      november;
     
  constructor(private _service : RegistrationService) {  
       this.getStatOctDetails();        
  }
    
       public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
        responsive: true,
        // We use these empty structures as placeholders for dynamic theming.
        scales: { xAxes: [{}], yAxes: [{}],
        plugins: {
          datalabels: {
            anchor: 'end',
            align: 'end',
          }
        }
      };
      public barChartLabels: Label[] = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
      public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
      public barChartLegend = true;
      public barChartPlugins = [pluginDataLabels];
    
      public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
        { data: [this.octomber, 7, 2, 9, 5, 3, 1], label: 'Series A' },
        { data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B' }
      ];
```

> **Property 'octomber' is used before its initialization** problem
> ocurred above lines

````
      ngOnInit(): void {
       
      }

      getStatOctDetails(){
        this._service.adminStatMonthOct().subscribe(
          data => {console.log(data)
          // this._router.navigate(['/login'])
          this.octomber = data;
    
        },
          error =>{ 
            console.log("error occur") 
            this.msg=error.error;
            ;
          }
        )
      } 
```
````

> I used spring boot framework and angular. value for octomber
> (variable) i take from spring boot. however i added null to octomber
> `(octomber=null;),` then error disappeared but did not display any value for my chart. **octomber value should be 2 for my project**

Comment: Please display your code properly (structure as well as highlighting) and show the code of your template (are you using 'octomber' in your template ?)

Comment: I need to take count of octomber  month from my database table ( from Month column ).  For that i use spring boot frame work. the spring boot part was right. it works well. But i cannot display count  of octomber in angular chart. i use angular charts for display count of octomber. Above code include all code of angular chart.  however i added null to octomber (octomber=null;), then error disappeared but did not display any value for my chart. octomber count should be 2 for my project

Comment: Where is the code below the constructor called and when? Probably it is a timing issue?
Do you call the code to set up the barChart before the request comes back from gathering your data ? Please make sure the barChart is set up AFTER this.octomber = data;